# How to install Polyglot on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-import, importerror, polyglot

When trying to run my server in python I got the following error:

> D:\WebServ 2\httpd>python server.py Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "server.py", line 7, in 
>       from word2vec import transform_text, getKthNeighbour, closest_k_points_tsne   File "D:\WebServ 2\httpd\word2vec.py", line 7,
>   in 
>       import polyglot ImportError: No module named polyglot

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your folders hieracy but it seems that `server.py` can't find your module. If you open `server.py` with the IDLE and go to >files>path browser, you should see anything like this:

```
--------------------------------------_OX
|/¬                                      |
| |-root/currentworkingdirectory         |
| |-usr/lib/python                       |
| |-usr/lib/python3.3                    |
| |-usr/lib/python/tkinter               |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

If the module is not in any of these folders, you will have to move it to there. If the code of your module is in a subfolder of one of these, import it like this:

```
from subfolder.subsubfolder.polyglot import *
```

Then you have to set '`polyglot.`' before all functoins, classes etc when you use a funcion, class, etc in `server.py`. I hope that's it, my programs work all like this.